# Vlookup then copy

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find a value in one sheet using a vlookup, assign that value to a variable, then copy it to another sheet.

For the Vlookup, I'm trying to find the values of POM&VENT as to be looked up as Value1Value3 .

I get an error telling me Object required.

```
Dim LookRangeT1 As Range

LookupRangeT1 = Sheets("T-1").Range("A20:S700")

Dim POM As String
POM = "Value1"

Dim VENT As String
VENT = "Value3"

Dim LookRangeT1 As Range
LookupRangeT1 = Sheets("T-1").Range("A20:S700")

Dim LookupCOT As Integer
LookupCOT = 16

Dim LookupCMP As Integer
LookupCMP = 17

Dim LookupRDI As Integer
LookupRDI = 18

Dim LookupCOF As Integer
LookupCOF = 19

Dim vResult As Integer
ExactMatch = False

Set vResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup((POM) & (VENT), 
LookupRangeT1, LookupCMP, ExactMatch)
vResult.Copy
Sheets("Endur T1").Activate
Range("O2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: You cannot set the return of the vlookup as it does not return a range but a value.  Remove the `Set` and simply assign the value: `Sheets("Endur T1").Range("O2").Value = vResult`